# Linked list node pointing to nodes of different type

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

This is my first post here, but I'm not new to the site (call me a lurker).
Unfortunately this time I cannot seem to find an answer to my question without asking.
Anyway, to the point.

I am writing a small snakes and ladders (aka chutes and ladders) program in java for a data structures course. I had to write my own Linked List (LL) class, (I know that there is a java util that does it better, but I have to learn about the workings of the data structure) and that is not a problem. My LL is 'semi-Double linked' as I like to call it, since it links forward, but has another pointer field for other links, which is not necessarily used in every node.

What I want to know is if it is possible to link a node from a list to another list, which is of a different type. 
Poor example:
(eg.) How would one link a node of type  to a node of type ? Let us say we have a LL of 7 int values [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], and a LL of 7 Strings [Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday,Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday]. We want to link the node containing 1 to the node containing Monday.

To be exact the problem I am having is as follows: 
I have 100  nodes forward-linked, forming the game board, and a circularly linked list of 4 . I want to link the player nodes to their respective positions on the board, so that as they traverse the board, they can also follow the "snakes" and "ladders" links.

Thanks in advance!

My LLNode.java and LL.java are attached.

```
// LLNode.java  
// node in a generic linked list class, with a link 

public class LLNode<T> 
{
    public T info;
    public LLNode<T> next, link;

    public LLNode()
    {   
        next = null;
        link= null;
    }

    public LLNode(T element)
    {
        info = element;
        next = null;
        link = null;
    }

    public LLNode(T element, LLNode<T> n)
    {
        info = element;
        next = n;
        link = null;
    }

    public T getInfo()
    {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(T element)
    {
        info = element;
    }

    public LLNode<T> getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(LLNode<T> newNext)
    {
        next = newNext;
    }

    public LLNode<T> getLink()
    {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(LLNode<T> newLink)
    {
        link = newLink;
    }
}

// SLL.java 
// a generic linked list class

public class LL<T> 
{
    private LLNode<T> head, tail;
    public LLNode<T> current = head;

    public LL()
    {
        head = tail = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return head == tail;
    }

    public void setToNull()
    {
         head = tail = null;
    }

    public boolean isNull()
    {
        if(head == tail)
            if(head == null || tail == null)
                return true;
            else 
                return false;
        else 
            return false;
    }

    public void addToHead(T element)
    {
        head = new LLNode<T>(element, head);
        if (tail == null)
            tail = head;
    }

    public void addNodeToHead(LLNode<T> newNode)
    {
        head = newNode;
        if (tail == null)
            tail = head;
    }

    public void addToTail(T element)
    {
        if (!isNull())
        {
            tail.next= new LLNode<T>(element);
            tail = tail.next;
        }
        else head = tail = new LLNode<T>(element);
    }

    public void addNodeToTail(LLNode<T> newNode)
    {
        if (!isNull())
        {
            tail.next= newNode;
            tail = tail.next;
        }
        else head = tail = newNode;
    }

    public void addBefore(T element, T X)
    {
        if (!isEmpty()) // Case 1
        {
            LLNode<T> temp, n;

            temp = head;
            while( temp.next != null )
            {
                if( temp.next.info == X )
                {
                    n = new LLNode<T>(element, temp.next);
                    temp.next = n;
                    return;
                }
                else 
                temp = temp.next;
            }    
        }
        else // Case 2
            head = new LLNode<T>(element, head);
    }

    public void addBefore(T element, LLNode<T> X)
    {
        if (!isEmpty()) // Case 1
        {
            LLNode<T> temp, n;

            temp = head;
            while( temp.next != null )
            {
                if( temp.next == X )
                {
                    n = new LLNode<T>(element, X);
                    temp.next = n;
                    return;
                }
                else 
                temp = temp.next;
            }    
        }
        else // Case 2
            head = new LLNode<T>(element, head);
    }

    public T deleteFromHead()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            return null;
        T element = head.info;
        if (head == tail)
            head = tail = null;
        else head = head.next;
        return element;
    }

    public T deleteFromTail()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            return null;
        T element = tail.info;
        if (head == tail)
            head = tail = null;
        else 
        {
            LLNode<T> temp;
            for (temp = head; temp.next != tail; temp = temp.next);
            tail = temp;
            tail.next = null;
        }
        return element;
    }

    public void delete(T element)
    {
        if (!isEmpty())
            if (head == tail && (element.toString()).equals(head.info.toString()))
                head = tail = null;
            else if ((element.toString()).equals(head.info.toString()))
                head = head.next;
        else 
        {
            LLNode<T> pred, temp;
            for (pred = head, temp = head.next; temp != null && !((temp.info.toString()).equals(element.toString())); pred = pred.next, temp = temp.next);
            if (temp != null)
                pred.next = temp.next;
            if  (temp == tail)
                tail = pred;
        }
    }

    public void listAll()
    {
        if(isNull())
            System.out.println("\tEmpty");
        else
        {
            for ( LLNode<T> temp = head; temp!= tail.next; temp = temp.next)
                System.out.println(temp.info);
        }
    }

    public LLNode<T> isInList(T element)
    {
        LLNode<T> temp;
        for ( temp = head; temp != null && !((temp.info.toString()).equals(element.toString())); temp = temp.next);
        return temp ;
    }

    public LLNode<T> getHead()
    {
        return head;
    }

    public LLNode<T> getTail()
    {
        return tail;
    }

    public LLNode<T> getCurrent()
    {
        return current;
    }

    public void incrementCurrent()
    {
        current = current.next;
    }

    public void followCurrentLink()
    {
        current = current.link;
    }
}
```

Comment: You included a lot of extra code there... Also, yeah, you can, but you end up with something more resembling a tree or a graph than a list.

Comment: Not sure if I've understood your question correctly - your example is too long - but if your two lists (linked or not) always have the same number of elements and are mapped to the same elements, you should have a single list, each element of which is another object with both attributes - here, day of the week, and name of day of the week.

Comment: This seems like a risky data structure. What happens if I delete Monday? It looks to me like 1 stays around. Can you list what operations you want to do? That should drive the design. For instance, doubly-linked list exists to allow fast insert and delete at the tail. What operations do you want to make easy and/or fast??

Comment: Sorry about that. I will put less next time. Yeah, a tree would be a better way to do this, but we **have** to use Linked Lists for this assignment. Ok, I see how the weekday example is confusing. I have a Linked list of 100 blocks ( the snakes and ladders board ), and a circularly linked list of 4 players, i want the players to link to their respective positions on the list. I will not be adding or deleting nodes.

Comment: @LosTheRed sounds like you want a [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any specific reason you want to generics for the specific problem domain of the node objects?

If you want to have this effect, another way to do it might be have an interface for node object (maybe call it ILinkNode), have the getInfo and setInfo overridden in two different node classes. Then the nodeLink can point to interface object without special type casting everywhere in the code.

Comment: That is a good idea! The Linked list I wrote was intentionally as generic as possible for reuse-ability.

Comment: @LosTheRed In that case, you might want to re-define the LLNode as LLNode<N, L>, where N is the type of next element and L the type of link. Your methods then can be type parametrized and you could have any typed instance of LLNode at any time. for example, in the same linked list, different nodes can have next and link of different types based on how they are constructed.

Comment: Thank you SO much! that is **exactly** what I needed! It works just as i want it to, and I learned something new! I was not aware one could use more than one template.

Answer (score 0):

Use in the first list, i.e. the one containing the node you want to link to the node in the other list, Object as the generic type instantiation.

Something like:

```
    LL<Object> ll = new LL<Object>();
```

If you do this, you have to take care to cast to the specific type, each time you retrieve a node's value from the list.

Comment: Unfortunately, my first LL is already instantiated to be an <Integer> and the other LL is a <String>, so that is actually where my problem is, if i understand you correctly.